# Scroll to pure javascript not working

Tags: javascript

Yes I am avoiding a 3rd party lib on purpose, very small app on mobile device and don't want to pull anything.

I am trying to scroll to elements on a page using this scrollTo function:

```
function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
    if (duration <= 0) return;
    var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
    var perTick = difference / duration * 10;

    setTimeout(function() {
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
        if (element.scrollTop === to) return;
        scrollTo(element, to, duration - 10);
    }, 10);
}
```

I grab a list of span tags that I want to use as my scroll points each time the user clicks a next button:

```
var index = null;
function next() {
    var list = document.querySelectorAll("span");

    var element = null;
    if (index == null) {
        index = -1;
        element = document.body;
    } else {
      element = list[index];
    }

    index++;
    if (index >= list.length) {
        return;
    }

    var to = list[index];

    scrollTo(element, to.offsetTop, 250);
}
```

The first next click properly scrolls to the first element.  However the next click does not scroll.  I debugged into the scrollTo method and it seems the element.scrollTop variable is not changing each time it is assigned.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that your var list has more than one item in it?

Comment: Yes, list has 4 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You musst change the `element.scrollTop` of the element you want to scroll on, in this case `document.body`. You are only doing this in the first call. After that you´re always scrolling on the list item which is your target (what has no effect, since it has no overflow).
You should call your `scrollTop` like this:

```
scrollTo(document.body, to.offsetTop, 250);
```

Maybe you should also take a look at

```
window.scrollTo()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Comment: This would cause it to always scroll to body. If you look at his code, you will see that he is setting element based on an incremented index. So, element should change every time you click next because index is being incremented.

Comment: No, his script changes the `scrollTop` of the given `element`, which is the scroll position.

Comment: I think I see what you mean, but if that's the case wouldn't he want to change element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick; to document.body = element.scrollTop + perTick;? He would still want to increment the element var to change the position I would think.

Comment: He could also do something like this. But this would make the function less flexible since it could not handle any other scrollable elements.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to replicate your exact issue, but what I did find was that I was not able to get to the last span with the way your code was written. To get around that, I rewrote a few things. It may fix the issue for you.

```
function next() {
    var list = document.querySelectorAll("span");

    var element = null;
    if (index == null) {
        index = -1;
        element = document.body;
    } else {
      element = list[index];
    }

    if (index >= list.length) {
        return;
    }

    if(index >= 0)
    {
        var to = list[index];    
        scrollTo(element, to.offsetTop, 250);

    }
    index++;
}
```

Essentially, you were trying to increment your index too soon causing it to never process the last span.